# Unable to execute "hive -e 'select * from table" using .exec() method of simple-ssh npm module

Tags: node.js, shell, unix, ssh, npm

I am unable to execute a `hive -e` command using simple-ssh module `.exec()` in nodejs.
I think there is a problem with the single/double quotes `'` or `"`. I don't know which quote to put in what sequence. I tried a lot of combination, but none of them worked.
Here is the code below:

```
var runSSH(obj){
    var ssh = new SSH({
        host: remote1,
        user: 'root',
        timeout: 1500000,
        key: require('fs').readFileSync("C:/Users/Aiman/Desktop/hRep_prv"),
        agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
        agentForward: true
    });

    ssh.exec('timeout 900 ssh -i /root/rsaPrvtKeyPath/to/remoteHost2 '+remoteHost2+' \'for i in '+remote3+' '+remote4+'; do clush -w ${i} "hive -e \'select * from table_name limit 3;\'" done\' ',{
            out: function(stdout) {
                devHive_check += stdout;
                obj.devHive_check = devHive_check;
                console.log(stdout);
            }
        }) //-->not executing
        .exec('timeout 300 ssh -i /root/rsaPrvtKeyPath/to/remoteHost2 '+remoteHost2+' \'for i in '+remote3+' '+remote4+'; do clush -w ${i} "ps -ef | grep HiveServer2"; done;\' ',{
            out: function(stdout) {
                devHS2_check += stdout;
                obj.devHS2_check = devHS2_check;
                console.log(stdout);
            }
        })//-->running fine
        .exec('echo "parse and save"',{
            out: function(){
                parseData(obj);
                ssh.end();
            }
        }).start(); //-->running fine
}
```

I am logging into remoteHost1, running a couple of shell scripts (which are runnig fine), then I am doing an `ssh` to remoteHost2 to check `Hive` (hive is running on remote3 and remote4).
`HiveServer2` is running fine, but `Hive` isn't.
Please help me.

Comment: Did you try using escaped double quotes instead of escaped single quotes around the actual query (`select * from table_name limit 3;`)?

Comment: yes. Its still not working. .exec('timeout 900 ssh -i '+rsaPath+' '+healthDevHost+' \'for i in '+hiveStageNodes+'; do clush -w ${i} "hive -e \"select * from base.merlin_tag limit 3\""; done;\' ')

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant double-escaped quotes (`\\"`). Otherwise the server will see a command like this: `timeout 900 ssh -i /foo.key foo.bar.baz 'for i in foo; do clush -w ${i} "hive -e "select * from base.merlin_tag limit 3""; done;'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solved now.
Instead of the single quotes inside `hive`, it requires a doulbe quotes, i.e. instead line `ssh.exec('timeout 900 ssh -i /root/rsaPrvtKeyPath/to/remoteHost2 '+remoteHost2+' \'for i in '+remote3+' '+remote4+'; do clush -w ${i} "hive -e \'select * from table_name limit 3;\'" done\' ',{`
I did
`ssh.exec('timeout 900 ssh -i /root/rsaPrvtKeyPath/to/remoteHost2 '+remoteHost2+' \'for i in '+remote3+' '+remote4+'; do clush -w ${i} "hive -e \\\"select * from table_name limit 3;\\\" " done\' ',{`, and it worked.
Thanks @mscdex for your support.